# How to read Enum member with FXCop SDK

Tags: fxcop

I am writing a customized rule for cheking Enum member value.
Can anyone helps me how can I read enum member with FxCop SDK.

I can read the Enum name but I have no idea how can I read Enum memebr name?

Please Help

Comment: Are you looking to get values or just the names?